# Próximo Código da Sequencia 0-Z com Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, lógica, programação-funcional

Preciso criar um função JavaScript que recebe uma string de letras e números e ele retorna o próximo valor da contagem. A contagem vai de 0 a Z. Exemplo da sequencia:

0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - A - B - C - D [...] Y - Z - 01 - 02 - 03 [...] 0Y - 0Z - 10 - 11 - 12 [...]

Exemplo da função:

nextCode ("AF10") // Retorna "AF11"

nextCode ("A4ZZ") // Retorna "A500"

---

O que eu tentei até o momento:

```
/*Gerar Novo Código*/
function nextCode(lastCode){
    //Verifica o Tamanho
    var codeSize = lastCode.length;
    //Verifica o index do ultimo caracter
    var indexLastValidChar = codeSize-1;
    //Se o ultimo caracter for igual a Z pega o caractere anterior (loop)
    var loopAtive;
    do {
        indexLastValidChar = loopAtive == true ?  indexLastValidChar-1 :indexLastValidChar;
        var lastValidChar = lastCode.substr(indexLastValidChar, 1);
        loopAtive = true;
    } while(lastValidChar == "Z");
    //Pega a primeira metade do novo código
    var firstHalfCode = lastCode.slice(0, indexLastValidChar);
    //Verifica se o ultimo caracter diferente de Z é numero ou letra
    var isChar = isNaN(parseInt(lastValidChar));
    //Se for char, gera o próximo caracter
    var newChar;
    if (isChar){
        newChar = String.fromCharCode(lastValidChar.charCodeAt(0)+1);
    } //Se não for, verifica se o número é 9
    else if (lastValidChar == "9") {
        newChar = "A";
    }  //Se não for, adicona um ao número
    else {
        newChar = parseInt(lastValidChar) + 1;
    }
    //Junta primeira metade
    firstHalfCode = firstHalfCode + newChar;
    //Adicona zeros ao final, caso codeSize seja diferente de indexLastValidChar+1 - ou seja, existem Zs
    for (var i = 0; i < codeSize - indexLastValidChar+1; i++) {
        var newCode = firstHalfCode + 0;
    }
    //Mostra o novo código
    console.log(newCode);
}
nextCode ("AF10");
nextCode ("A4ZZ");
```

Os resultados não dão certo e estou meio perdido...

Comment: Adicione à sua pergunta aquilo que já tem até agora.

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta !

Comment: Isso me parece que você está querendo trabalhar com base 36. Depois de Z não veria o valor 10? Precisa que depois de Z seja mesmo 01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sabes a *String* que tens de caracteres podes usar um loop para fazer essas mudanças/incrementações. Usando flags para coltrolar se deve incrementar.

Sugestão:

```js
var Next = (function(seq) {
  var lastChar = seq.slice(-1);

  return function(str) {
    if (!str) return '0';
    var chars = str.split('');
    var raize = true,
      addChar = false;
    for (var i = chars.length - 1; i + 1; i--) {
      var charIndex = seq.indexOf(chars[i]);
      if(!raize) continue;
      if (chars[i] !== lastChar) {
        if (!raize) break;
        chars[i] = seq[charIndex + 1];
        raize = false;
      } else {
        chars[i] = seq[0];
        raize = true;
        if (raize && i == 0) chars.unshift(seq[0]);
      }
    }
    return chars.join('');
  }

})('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ');

['', '00', '0Z', 'ZZ', 'AF10', 'A4ZZ', 'A4Z0'].forEach(test => console.log(test, Next(test)));
```

Comment: Se for seguir o modelo proposto na pergunta, tem um problema. Next('A4Z0') está retornando "A501", algo que deveria ser somente para "A500".

Comment: Também está faltando a letra Y na inicialização do Next.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura bem visto, corrigi!

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio ! Fiquei impressionado, pois serve também para outras sequencias, basta alterar os parâmetros na invocação do IIFE. Eu testei com outras sequencias e funciona legal. Parabéns.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo entendimento da pergunta, parece que está querendo trabalhar com uma base 36, porém o exemplo de sequência descrito na pergunta não cai direito na base 36. Os exemplos de sequências de "AF10" -> "AF11" e "A4ZZ" -> "A500" estão corretos, mas seguindo a base 36 o número após "Z" seria "10". Se for esse o caso, basta usar as funções `parseInt` e `String.prototype.toString`, que permitem passar a base por parâmetro.

```
var nextCode = function(number) {
  var inBase10 = parseInt(number, 36);
  return (inBase10 + 1).toString(36).toUpperCase();
};

nextCode('AF10'); // => "AF11"
nextCode('A4ZZ'); // => "A500"
```

Comment: Boa resposta! `+1`

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, acho que uma sequencia na base 36 é realmente mais coerente. Boa resposta. Pouco código e muito efetiva.